# Customize editor.autoSurround for a particular Language

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the settings `"editor.autoSurround": "languageDefined"`.

I want to disable `"blockComment": ["/*", "*/"]` for `"[asciidoc]"`, so that if i select a text then press  <kbd>*</kbd> , it replace the selected text with  <kbd>*</kbd>  instead of surround the text with  <kbd>*</kbd> .

I have tried https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax with the settings:

```
"custom-language-properties": {
  "asciidoc.comments.blockComment": "",
  "asciidoc.comments.lineComment": ""
}
```

Not working.

What might be the solution here?

Comment: Are you using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asciidoctor.asciidoctor-vscode as your asciidoc language extension?

Comment: yes i am using the asciidoc language extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of that extension.  Modifying surrounding pairs, as you probably know, is not supported by the extension because the vscode api (see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#LanguageConfiguration) does not support modifying surrounding pairs.  So the easy solution of deleting the

```
[
   "*",
   "*"
],
```

entry in `surroundingPairs` cannot work through the extension.  Maybe someday, as support for `autoClosingPairs` is being worked on right now.

You can easily modify the language configuration file yourself though.  With an `asciidoc` file open, trigger the command `Custom Language Properties: Show Language Configuration for Current Editor`.  That will open the language configuration file - **any** changes you make to that file will be saved to that language extension.  Since it is a `jsonc` file, you can just comment out the surrounding pairs `*` case I mentioned above.

Then if you select text and hit `*` the text will be replaced by `*` and not surrounded by asterisks.  It works, I tested it.

The only problem with this method is that any updates to the asccidoc extension may override any changes you made to the configuration file - and you would have to re-do your changes (which as you saw is pretty easy with the command I mentioned above).

---

By the way, I don't understand why you were changing the comment styles to effect a change in autoSurround?

Comment: Is there any way i can create an override file for Language Configuration (so that updating asccidoc extension does not affect the changes)?

Comment: No, I don't believe there is any way to prevent that.  Every update to the asciidoc extension may not change its language configuration file though - I am not sure if all files get overwritten on an extension update or just the modified files get updated.